# Concurrent Remote Desktop Assistance

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, windows-networking, remote-assistance, ultravnc

I maintain a network of apx. 60-80 computers.  Normally I can remote desktop into these machines via a windows domain.  I'm for the most part self-taught however and I was wondering what is the typical method of remotely supporting an end user without logging them out of the machine?  A lot of the people on my network provide critical services (such as emergency call operations) or have user dependent applications which do not allow me to log them out and I need to be logged into them to configure them.  I've used and know of:

- Ultra VNC
- TeamViewer
- LogMeIn
- Standard Windows Remote Desktop

Is there an option on Windows RDC that will allow this?  Or should I start installing Ultra VNC on the machines?

Thanks

Comment: Also see: http://superuser.com/questions/317312/remote-management-of-parents-computers, http://superuser.com/questions/103644/free-remote-desktop-app-good-for-working-with-someone-computer-illiterate, http://superuser.com/questions/55718/remote-connection-to-a-pc-over-internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is Remote Assistance if you are looking for something native. Essentially, it lets you RDP on to a users machine while they remain logged in.

[Here is a TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457004.aspx) on how to get started.

[Another FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-remote-assistance-faq#1TC=windows-8) I found with Google.

Answer (score 0):

Windows wasn't made as a multi-user OS, so you'd need to do some [ugly modifications](http://lifehacker.com/5873717/enable-concurrent-remote-desktop-sessions-in-windows-with-this-patch) to get RDP working the way you want, I've used it and it works well, but pushing it out to a large network might be difficult.