# How to ask for help using Skype

Tags: remote-desktop, skype, remote, remote-access, remote-assistance

I'm using Skype (latest version 2014). There's some problem with my computer so I want to ask for help.

How to give full access (view screen, control inputs) to my friend on Skype?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible with Skype. It only allows you to share your screen. You cannot give control over your desktop to others.

For alternatives, see:

- [Remote management of parents' computers](https://superuser.com/questions/317312/remote-management-of-parents-computers/)
- [Free remote desktop app good for working with someone computer illiterate?](https://superuser.com/questions/103644/free-remote-desktop-app-good-for-working-with-someone-computer-illiterate)
- [Remote connection to a PC over internet](https://superuser.com/questions/55718/remote-connection-to-a-pc-over-internet)
- and many others

Also, check out the [comparison of remote desktop software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @slhck - It seems you can't with Skype.

But a (seemingly??) little-known fact, is that you have been able to get 'Remote Assistance' in Microsoft Windows since XP. Even most of the links supplied by @slhck don't seem to mention this.
(It's not the best out there, but it works.)

It's just a few clicks away.
In XP: Start -> Help and Support -> "Invite a friend... with Remote Assistance"
In Windows 7: Start/Orb -> Type 'remote assistance' -> Select 'Windows Remote assistance'

Similar in other windows versions.

Follow the instructions.
You will need to be able to send an email to the 'helper'. Or get some access details to them another way. (Text message or phone call probably)
Firewalls may cause issues to, but I usually find it works.

I can't believe how few people seem to know about this.

Comment: That's all very interesting but nothing in the question says the asker is using Windows.