# Dual logins on same session, windows 7

Tags: windows-7, remote-access

I have a Windows 7 computer at home. I want to connect remotely to it, but don't want it to logout the current session.

What I want is to be able to log in from 2 places but still only 1 session so I don't need to retype my password every time.

Does anyone know how or if this is possible at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free remote desktop app good for working with someone computer illiterate?](http://superuser.com/questions/103644/free-remote-desktop-app-good-for-working-with-someone-computer-illiterate)

Comment: Not meaning to imply you are computer illiterate, just that it has some good suggestions

Answer (score 1):

as per i know and done, you can make one program that listen to your commands and also shares current screen with you,
so you can pass specific commands (ms-dos commands), depending what kind of action you want to take.

*i actually made for my uncle, who chkeck what her daughter his doing by sitting in office and, can control access*

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel\System and Security\System
Remote settings - allow Remote Desktop

Yes, it possible. With a Remote Desktop connection.

Update:
You can use [Real VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/) to work from several PC at the same time. (but it's not free)

Comment: no, im not that stupid , i wana be loged on over remote and at the pc at same time

Comment: you will be logged, but if you want to work at the same time, it's another question.

Comment: yep, same time..want see my mouse pointer 2 places, 1)remote and 2) main workstation

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like http://logmein.com.
This is much easier to setup as VNC for remote access through a NATting router.