# remote desktop through inter net

Tags: remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote connection to a PC over internet](https://superuser.com/questions/55718/remote-connection-to-a-pc-over-internet)

how to connect 2 pc through internet?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx), as it's:

- Free to use
- Compatible with Windows, Linux, Mac OSX
- Connects all PCs, even both with passive IPs

Works every time!